# How can I use Docker Hub in Terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform

The instructions in [Terraform Docker Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/) give the example:

```
# Configure the Docker provider
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376/"
}

# Create a container
resource "docker_container" "foo" {
  image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"
  name  = "foo"
}

resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu:latest"
}
```

I'm assuming this is pointing to an on-prem docker source. How do I used [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [docker_registry_image](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/d/registry_image.html):

```
data "docker_registry_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu:latest"
}

resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name          = "${data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name}"
  pull_triggers = ["${data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.sha256_digest}"]
}
```